# Spring mvc form error mapping 2 models

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

when I try to open from url the create form I'm having an error.  I have 2 models that are mapped as one to many and using autopopulatinglist:

ContractHeader.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT_HEADER")
public class ContractHeader {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contractHeader")
    private List<ContractEntitlement> contractEntitlements;

    @Column(name = "customer_name")
    private String customerName;

    getter and setter ....
}
```

ContractEntitlement.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRACT_ENTITLEMENT")
public class ContractEntitlement {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ContractHeader contractHeader; 

    getter and setter ....
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(Model model) {
    ContractHeader ch = new ContractHeader();
    ch.setContractEntitlements(new AutoPopulatingList<ContractEntitlement>(ContractEntitlement.class));

    model.addAttribute("createForm", ch);

    return "create";
}
```

Create.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="createForm" action="${addAction}">
<table>
        <tr>
        <td>                  
            <form:input path="customerName" size="40" />
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

The error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contractEntitlement' available as request attribute

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contractEntitlement' available as request attribute
```

What I don't understand is why is saying contractEntitlement when my input path object is from the ContractHeader class.

My hibernate config

```
<mapping class="com.at.ccts.model.ContractHeader" />
<mapping class="com.at.ccts.model.ContractEntitlement" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that that is full JSP you are posting here...

Comment: It's not, its just the form of the jsp.

Comment: Please add the full JSP instead of a snippet.

Comment: You are right, ill post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is in my jsp i commented out:

```
<!--    <td>
        <form:input name="category" type="text" path="contractEntitlement.category"/>
        </td>  -->
```

But for some reason spring still checks it and throws an error.  Deleting the pirece of code fixed it.  I wonder why since it's  out.  Anyway this fixed my issue and the page is now loading properly.